# Woocommerce_log too big database folder

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't find answers to my question so I'm doing it. My site's database occupies 10.9 Gb of which 10.5 is the woocommerce_log folder, what can I do?? Can older logs be deleted? Is there a problem with the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder and Database are 2 different things.

> 10.5 is the woocommerce_log folder

You've mentioned folder but wrote the table name so it's confusing if you're talking about folder or database table.

however, if you are talking about the folder with the path `wp-content/uploads/wc-logs` then yes you can delete all the files with the extension `.log`

if you're talking about database table `wp_woocommerce_log` then generally it should be empty unless your log handler is set to DB. you can empty data from this table as well. **but don't delete the table**.

You also need to look in `wp-config.php` if you have defined a logger using constant `WC_LOG_HANDLER` you should use a file logging system instead of DB.

You can find more details on the WooCommerce logger on this page. https://developer.woocommerce.com/2017/01/26/improved-logging-in-woocommerce-2-7/

Comment: Sorry, I meant the table. So my first step is to delete every record in this table without deleting the table itself and then swich to a file logging system, right? Deleting all the data in the table will not create problems in woocommerce?

Comment: Yes, deleting the log data won't create any issue, but if you want to be careful you can export the table data before deleting the record.

Answer (score 0):

post_meta (in WordPress or WooCommerce) is inefficiently indexed. Suggest you add this plugin: WP Index Improvements

More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

(Deleting unused data from any big table rarely helps as much as improving the indexes.)